# How can i send a html mail with an attachment through Unix Shellscripting

Tags: unix

I am totally new to unix shellscripting.I have to send a html mail with a gzip file as an attachment through unix shell scripting without using uuencode or mailx.I have got several codes for this using uuencode and mailx but i need one without these.I m stuck.Please help me out.

Comment: The normal method for attachments _is_ uuencode piped though mailx or equivalent, why can you not use this?

Comment: what i have heard is that using uuencode and mailx are somewhat unsafe . Am i correct?

Comment: Err, no, not really. If you have specific problems, we'd love to see them.

Comment: @Manu: A couple of tips: 1. Never discard solutions out of hand because you have *heard* something. Always get a concrete answer on their applicability first. 2. When you ask questions on SO (or anywhere else, I suppose) please *explain* any restrictions. Otherwise there is no way for us to know if our potential solution violates those restrictions or not - not to mention that they might be completely invalid.

Comment: i need to send a html mail which is not possible through mailx.I need the mail to be well formatted which is not possible through uuencode and mailx.I want to use the SendMail utility.please help me out.

Comment: It is certainly possible to *send* HTML email via `uuencode` and `mailx`, just not *compose* such a beast. `sendmail` certainly can't create HTML emails! Perhaps, if you're new to shell-scripting, you could attempt this in another language, like Python. If this isn't an option, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and update your question to explain why you have to do this in a shell script.

Comment: This is my code.
{
echo "someone@someone.com"
echo "To: "From:someone@someone.com"
echo "Mime-Version: 1.0 "$version 
echo "Content-Type: Multipart/Mixed"
echo "Subject: Test"
echo "---q1w2e3r4t5-"
echo "Content-type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII" 
echo "Content-transfer-encoding: 7BIT" 
echo "---q1w2e3r4t5-"
echo "Content-type: Application/Octet-stream; name=text_file.tar.gz; type=Binary"
echo "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=text_file.tar.gz" 
echo "Content-transfer-encoding: X-UUencode"
echo ""
uuencode text_file.tar.gz text_file.tar.gz
} /usr/lib/sendmail -v

Answer (score 0):

You do have to use uuencode if there will be an attachment. The trick is to write out a plain ascii file that is formatted in a particular way. There is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134857/using-sendmail-for-html-body-and-binary-attachment) in this post. As long as your script writes out a file in that format, with the attachment uuencoded between the $MAILPART sections, it will be processed by sendmail and rendered nicely in the recipient's email program.