# Using sendmail for HTML body and binary attachment

Tags: shell, unix, sendmail, ksh, uuencode

Objective: To send mail (using sendmail) with HTML body and binary attachment.

Followed the guidelines specified in the following links

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/159522-sendmail-html-body-attachment-2.html

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/58448-sendmail-attachment.html

It is working to the extent that, either HTML body or the binary attachment with uuencode, but not both.

Given below is a snippet of the shell script to sendmail.  With this, the HTML body is coming fine, but the attachment is getting encoded/decoded wrongly and unable to view the same.

Please advise.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

export MAILFROM="noreply@site.dom"
export MAILTO="somebody@somesite.com"
export SUBJECT="Test PDF for Email"
export BODY="email_body.htm"
export ATTACH="file.pdf"
export MAILPART=`uuidgen` ## Generates Unique ID
(
 echo "From: $MAILFROM"
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"-$MAILPART\""
 echo "---$MAILPART"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo "---$MAILPART"
 echo 'Content-Type: application/pdf; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 uuencode -m $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
 echo "---$MAILPART--"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```

I am using HP-UX ia64.
Have searched through the forum and web and found references mostly to PHP, Python, etc.

Comment: Using `mutt -a` is much easier: http://www.mutt.org/doc/man_page.html

Comment: Thanks, but the current server setup restricts me to sendmail only :-(.  Also, mutt is not installed/setup on the server

Comment: Send HTML body email with a plain text attachment with sendmail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line/14213935#14213935

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changing the Content transfer encoding type within the email from base64 to uuencode resolved the issue.
Thanks for the inputs so far.

Given below is the revised script that works.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

export MAILFROM="noreply@domain.com"
export MAILTO="mail.to@gmail.com"
export SUBJECT="Test PDF for Email"
export BODY="email_body.htm"
export ATTACH="file.pdf"
export MAILPART=`uuidgen` ## Generates Unique ID
export MAILPART_BODY=`uuidgen` ## Generates Unique ID

(
 echo "From: $MAILFROM"
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$MAILPART\""
 echo ""
 echo "--$MAILPART"
 echo "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$MAILPART_BODY\""
 echo ""
 echo "--$MAILPART_BODY"
 echo "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 echo "You need to enable HTML option for email"
 echo "--$MAILPART_BODY"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo "--$MAILPART_BODY--"

 echo "--$MAILPART"
 echo 'Content-Type: application/pdf; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo ""
 #uuencode -m $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
 uuencode $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
 echo "--$MAILPART--"
) > email_`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`.out
| /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```

Comment: How do we do it for multiple attachments?

Comment: @divinedragon, you repeat the code from `echo "--$MAILPART"` to before `echo "--$MAILPART--"`. That's what adds one attachment.

Comment: That's TRUE MAGIC!!! Amazing!  I used it to attach multiple log files to my cronjobs reports...

Answer (score 0):

try adding a new line after `uuencode`

and try also without `-m`

Comment: uuencode -m is adding a new line at the end automatically.  I had already tried with -m and it did not work either.  I have tried again both suggestions from you and the same problem (attachment comes, but invalid).