# can git send-email send diff patch of html format?

Tags: python, html, git, sendmail, git-diff

I am using `git send-email` to email patch but i wanted to send the colour diff so I converted `diff.patch` file to `colour_diff.html` using [ansi2HTML](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansi2html/0.9.3) converter plugin in python but it saves file to html , so I am trying to send this html file now but when I try to send I get this error message

```
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 568.
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 575.
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 575.
fatal: failed to stat
```

is their any way to get this to work or do I have to use smtplib module to email html diff patch ?

Comment: so I have figured out how to send html diff but `git send-email` just dumps html in email instead of embedding HTML formatting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using sendmail for HTML body and binary attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134857/using-sendmail-for-html-body-and-binary-attachment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up writing my own tool to send git diff by email.
I cannot post the whole code here since its too lengthy .

I have put link here: [git maildiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/maildiff)